# Query regarding the user experience for upgrading from Free to Paid app on Google Play Store

Tags: android

I have a query regarding the user experience for upgrading from Free to Paid app on Google Play Store.

We are working on an Android app where we require to have both the Free and Paid version of the app on Google Play Store.

1. What is the best user experience, when the user upgrades from the free to paid version?

   a. Option 1: Install the paid app then send a message to the Android OS to remove the free app (this will have to done programmatically since the package names are different).
   Note: Package names have to unique for the apps to be published on Play Store.

   b. Option 2: Install the paid app and do not remove the free app. The user can then manually remove the free app.
2. Even when we programmatically try to remove the free app the Android OS prompts a confirmation message seeking users permission to remove the free app. If the user denies the permission then the free app is not uninstalled and the user will again have both the apps.

Is any way to programmatically uninstall an app without getting user confirmation(on a device that is not-rooted)? Since both the apps are published by us.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best user experience, when the user upgrades from the free to paid version?

Neither, really. You should be using in app billing instead to unlock premium features.

> Is any way to programmatically uninstall an app without getting user confirmation(on a device that is not-rooted)? Since both the apps are published by us.

No.